# Deletar um usuario do firebase Auth quando uma activity é destruída

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tenho uma Activity chamada `ValidadorActivity`, nessa Activity eu faço uma validação por *SMS*, logo após o usuário se cadastrar.

O cadastro é feito pelo `Firebase` Auth porém é feito antes dessa validação, então eu procuro um jeito de deletar o registro do Firebase quando o usuário sair da tela de validação sem colocar o Token que foi enviado por *SMS* corretamente.

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //Ao fechar completamente a tela de validação com o campo textValidacao nulo ou incorreto, o cadastro no autenticacao e no banco de dados sao apagados, para evitar o cadastro de usuarios não validados.

        String codigoDigitado = codigoValidacao.getText().toString(); //Pega o texto da caixa de texto

        if (! codigoDigitado.equals(tokenGerado)) {//Verifica se esse texto e igual

            user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() { //deleta o usuario no Auth
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {//Testa para ver se funcionou

                        Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Sim");


                    }else{

                        Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Não");

                    }

                }
            });
}
```

Porém ele não está deletando, creio eu que o código esteja certo. Alguma ideia ou sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Opa, blza!?

Será no onDestroy mesmo, mas antes de excluir um usuário é preciso que autentique ele novamente, entao pegue os dados da activity anterior e passar para essa:

```
     final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

     // Obtenha credenciais de autenticação do usuário para nova autenticação. O exemplo abaixo mostra
     // credenciais de e-mail e senha, mas há vários provedores possíveis,
     // como GoogleAuthProvider ou FacebookAuthProvider.
    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
            .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");

    user.reauthenticate(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
       user.delete()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Conta deletada");
                }
            }
        });

   }
});
```

Para saber mais detalhes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Se você quiser que a autenticação de usuário seja com outro provider de Singin, será preciso mudar o Provider para GoogleAuthProvider. A seguir um código de exemplo:

```
GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken,null);
```

Comment: Deixe me ver se entendi... por causa do onDrestroy, eu tenho q autenticar novamente o usuário para excluir, pois eu usei esse mesmo código num botão e ele funcionou normalmente. Então o motivo de eu precisar autenticar novamente o usuario é pq estou destruindo a activity?

Comment: Importante: para que seja possível excluir um usuário, é preciso que ele tenha feito login recentemente. Consulte o artigo Reautenticar um usuário.

Comment: Esta informação está na documentação, é preciso garantir um acesso recente dele para que vc possa excluir ele: veja nesse topico da documentação: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: Então no caso, ele acabou de fazer o login, logo após ele fazer o login, ele cai nessa tela q é um tela de verificação, e ai testa se o token gerado e igual e tals

Comment: Cara eu fiz um teste aqui, e ele não está nem passando pelo trecho do código, quando eu fecho a activity. Eu clico para abrir todos os aplicativos e depois fecho ele mas o tenho do código no destroy nem executa!

Comment: por via das duvidas, passe como parametro o usuario e senha, no onDestroy, coloque o codigo antes so super.onDestroy
Coloque um debug na aplicacao, quando minimizar, ele para no onPause
mas quando vc fechar ela, cai no onDestroy

Comment: Então, depois de fazer diversos testes descobri que o onDestroy só é ativado quando a activity é encerrada pelo sistema, não quando vc força ela a se fechar, como por exemplo quando aperta o botão direto e arrasta ela para fechar, alguém teria algum jeito de acessar esse código sempre que a activity fosse fechada?

Comment: O que vc pode fazer é o seguinte, salva o status que se encontra no sharedPreference do android.
Caso ele feche o App ou mate a atividade, no onCreate e no onRestart vc verifica o status da conta (pendente, efetivado, nao iniciado, null, sla vai depender do seu caso).
caso de pendente vc poderá excluir o usuário e montar a tela novamente pata ele fazer o procedimento novamente.

Comment: Cara pensei nisso, porem queria uma solução dessa maneira. Mas valeu cara, estou achando q vou precisar fazer dessa maneira mesmo! Obg!

Comment: Ja fiz algo parecido, caso precise tenho o codigo aqui pra gravar e recuperar no sharedPreferences

Comment: Obrigado! Tenho o código aqui tbm.